# why react application is not loading js bundle in appengine server

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine

React app which works great in local and aws. But in Google App Engine, when deployed using

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

opens white fresh website which contains the index.html content inside; in the page source like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webapp" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/loading.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"/>    
</body>
</html>
```

And does not load the js bundle. I couldnt see any clue in the browser and server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you want to host the React.js front-end and Java back end project that is build by maven. But It’s difficult to merge a React.js project built with NPM and a Java back-end project built with Maven into one deploy-able package in Google Cloud Patform.

So As an altenative, you can use [Google microservices within an App engine project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/microservices-on-app-engine). You can follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@Leejjon_net/how-i-ended-up-running-a-react-js-front-end-and-java-back-end-on-google-app-engine-85158c117e99) to solve your issue.

If you have only a Reactjs project so [here](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/deploying-react-app-to-google-app-engine-a6ea0d5af132) is a tutorial, how to deploy React App to Google Cloud App Engine.

Comment: Yes. Your assumption is right. And I am following your link. But something strange happens. Even though the js bundle is not loaded opening the `context root /`, if I try something like `/login` it is suddenly opened and loaded the bundle and worked fine.

Comment: I think because you're defining somewhere that the starting route is /login and not /. Check your .js classes where you're defining or creating routes. 
Thank you for accepting my answer :)